# How to add multiple SCNScenes to one SCNScene?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

I am trying to create an application that will allow to place 3d objects. I was able to write some code that works, but only with geometric objects. I need to add multiple SCNScenes to one scene. How do I implement this?

How I have tried:

```
let sceneView = SCNView()
sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
sceneView.backgroundColor = .gray
    
let firstScene = SCNScene(named: "Earth.usdz")!
let firstSceneNode = firstScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Earth", recursively: true)!
firstSceneNode.rotate(by: .init(0, 0, 0, 0), aroundTarget: SCNVector3(0, -30, 10))
sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(firstSceneNode)
    
let secondScene = SCNScene(named: "Venus.usdz")!
let secondSceneNode = secondScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Venus", recursively: true)!
sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(secondSceneNode)
```

When I delete secondScene everything works with one model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SceneKit each SCNScene can contain multiple SCNNodes connected to scene's `root` node. As you can see on the image these nodes can be not only geometry but also light fixtures, cameras or particle systems.

[image]

You can easily retrieve any desirable SCNNode with corresponding materials from any SCNScene tree and paste in into other scene (in this case into empty scene).

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        SceneKitView().ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct SceneKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let sceneView = SCNView(frame: .zero)

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = .black
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
        
        let scene01 = SCNScene(named: "Earth.usdz")!
        let scene02 = SCNScene(named: "Mars.usdz")!
        let scene03 = SCNScene(named: "Sun.usdz")!

        let earthNode = scene01.rootNode.childNode(withName: "earthPlanet", 
                                                recursively: true)!
        earthNode.position.x = -1.0

        let marsNode = scene02.rootNode.childNode(withName: "marsPlanet", 
                                               recursively: true)!
        marsNode.position.x = 0.2

        let sunNode = scene03.rootNode.childNode(withName: "sunStar", 
                                              recursively: true)!
        sunNode.position.x = 1.5
        
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(earthNode)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(marsNode)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(sunNode)
        return sceneView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SCNView, context: Context) { }
}
```

P.S.

**But you can't load multiple SCNScenes into single SCNScene**.

Comment: I tried this method, but unfortunately I get: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You get error in case a name of a node in scene is erroneous. A name of a node in `Scene graph` may not be the same as a name of `usdz` file.

Comment: name of a node if correctly. The scene is displayed correctly in the preview, but the application crashes in the simulator

Comment: Mine works fine. I'll publish full SwiftUI code in 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm waiting

Comment: Code's ready and I can say one more time that app works fine.

Comment: Pay attention, your code is full of errors – your second scene is named: `Venus.usdz.usdz`. And next line also causes error – `let secondSceneNode = secondScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Venus.usdz")` – because in Scene graph there's no `childNode(withName: "Venus.usdz")`, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, this was my mistake, I used Venus.usdz and withName: Venus in my code. 
i copied your code but the error is still the same. 
I will try to download models from apple and use the code with them. After a recent update I had to rollback xcode, maybe because of this problem

Comment: It's works, it seems the problem was still in the models, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply take the nodes you want out of each child scene (in this case it looks like you want the root node from each planet scene) and [add](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407974-addchildnode) them each as as child node in the scene you are going to present (ie a solar system scene).

Comment: extension SCNNode {

    convenience init(named name: String) {
        self.init()

        guard let scene = SCNScene(named: name) else {
            return
        }

        for childNode in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
            addChildNode(childNode)
        }
    }

}. Right?